# Pulling out a variable from a Schubert polynomial

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

Let $\mathfrak S_w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a Schubert polynomial. It's known that if we pick an index $i$, there are nonnegative integer coefficients $c_{w'}^w(i,j)$ such that
$$\mathfrak S_w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{w'\in S_\infty,j}c_{w'}^w(i,j)x_i^j\mathfrak S_{w'}(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$$
When $i=1$, Bergeron and Billey found a positive formula for $c_{w'}^w(i,j)$. I know a positive formula for all $i$, but I'm wondering if anyone else does. Does anyone have a reference?

I'm writing about it in a paper, and it would actually make my paper more interesting if someone else found a formula for it, especially if it was found before $1995$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in a Section five of a paper of mine with Bergeron in the Transactions of the AMS, which identifies it.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. Do you know of one for double Schubert polynomials as well? I have a positive formula for pulling out $x_i$ from a double Schubert polynomial in terms of $(x_i-y_j)$ and a complementary double Schubert polynomial and if that's not new it's also important to know that. It relies on the Pieri formula in my upcoming paper that's still under consideration.